# turning a string into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var objectHTMLCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("select"),
string = [].map.call( objectHTMLCollection, function(node){
    return node.id || "";
}).join(" ");
```

I have this code which converts an `[object HTMLCollection]` into a string I am wanting to turn it into an array.
So say they output was `hello world I am here` would become `[hello,world,I,am,here]`

Comment: Doesn't `[].map.call` already return an array and you're just making it a string with `.join(" ")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split(" ")`

```
var stringArray = string.split(" ");
```

OR you can prepare array while preparing string, see below code

```
var stringArray = new Array();
var objectHTMLCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("select"),
string = [].map.call( objectHTMLCollection, function(node){
    stringArray.push(node.id);
    return node.id || "";
}).join(" ");
```

Comment: should be `push` instead of `put`

Comment: Oh yeah ... sorry my bad. Corrected now, thanks @RussCam

Answer (score 1):

Map already returns an array. No need to turn it into a string then back into an array.

```js
var objectHTMLCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("select"),
idarray = [].map.call( objectHTMLCollection, function(node){
    return node.id || "";
}), string = idarray.join(' ');

document.write('<div>String: ' + string + '<div>');
document.write('Array: ' + JSON.stringify(idarray) + '<div>');
```

```html
<select id='dsada1'></select>
<select id='dsada2'></select>
<select></select>
<select id='dsada4'></select>
<select id='dsada5'></select>
<select id='dsada6'></select>
<br/><br/>
```